# sum of digits of a power of $12$ or $123$, e.g. $12^{3222}$ or $123^{234}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's just consider these two specific cases: $12^{3222}$ and $123^{234}$

My thoughts:

1. There really are not many nice properties of the "sum of digits".
2. Their bases are both a multiple of 3. So their sum of digits will both be multiples of 9.
3. The total number of digits in a number $N$ is $n = 1 + log_{10} N$, so the sum of digits of, say, $12^{3222}$ is between $3n = 3\times (1+log_{10} N)$ and $9n = 9\times(1+log_{10}N)$ (most likely between $3n$ and $6n$ I guess but have no proof)
4. Using elementary number theories, I can determine the last two digits of the powers. But totally have no idea about sum of the digits.
5. Thinking about leveraging the binomial theorem, i.e.
   $$12^{3222} = (10 + 2)^{3222}$$
   $$123^{234} = (100 + 23)^{234}$$
   but they are getting messy quickly.

Any suggestions? Or is there an iterative (or recursive) method, that may be used for a program?

Comment: These numbers are not so big.  You could just ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+digits+of+12%5E3222)

Comment: Or if you are programming, with a package that can handle arbitrary-length integers, just compute $12^{3222}$ or $123^{234}$ , convert to decimal and add the digits.

Comment: There is no "efficient" method to determine the digit sum of a huge power. You just need the complete number and have to add the digits.